# Manage micro-service from a container

Tags: docker, microservices, swarm

What is the best practice to have a micro-service application configured by the customer.

**The use case**

- The customer configure which services are available from an HTTP server
- According to the customer configuration, the dockers containing the services will be started.

**Some objectives to achive**

- Launch short lived application
- Avoid asking the DevOps to configure business
- Run micro-services only when necessary, avoid to run some services not used for business application
- Easy to deploy (local, AWS, Azure...)

**Possible solution ?**

- Docker in a docker (apparently not recommanded)
  [jpetazzo advices](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)
- Mapping the docker socket

  > docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ..
- ... ?

Comment: I seek for a solution to easily deploy my application to customer. In most of the situation (AWS, Azure, ...). If I am not **inside** a docker. I need to install my "managing" application in the host.

Comment: take a look at `portainer` project.

Comment: Thanks I will, at first glance that's seem to fit my needs